# как в placeholder цвет сделать черным а звездочку красной

Tags: css, html5, вёрстка

[image: gtml]

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать

Comment: Никак. Это сделано через элемент с абсолютной позицией и отцентрированый по центру.

Comment: @MoloF здравствуйте насколько я знаю можно, подожду ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это фейковый placeholder... например, span - который с абсолютной позицией будет стоять за слоем инпута, у которого прозрачный бэкграунд. Во время печати - делать надпись невидимой. Без JS не получится, потому что надо проверять - заполнен ли инпут. И возвращать placeholder на место, когда оно окажется пустым.

```js
let bubu = document.querySelectorAll('.bubu');
let hold = document.querySelectorAll('.bubuholder');

for(let i = 0; i < bubu.length; i++){
  bubu[i].addEventListener('input', function(){
    hold[i].style.display = ( this.value == "" ) ? 'inline' : 'none';
  });
}
```

```css
.bubuholder span {color: red;}
.mama {
  position: relative; 
  margin: 5px;
  height: 25px;
}
.bubuholder {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px; top: 2px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.bubu {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid #123;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.bubu:focus ~ .bubuholder{
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="mama">
  <input class="bubu">
  <span class="bubuholder">Ваш номер телефона<span>*</span></span>
</div>

<div class="mama">
  <input class="bubu">
  <span class="bubuholder">Ваш номер бубуфона<span>*</span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: позже ознакомлюсь

Comment: здравствуйте пожалуйста  скажите wp знаете ?

Comment: @Leks Дратути, нет...

Comment: спасибо за ответ, удачи

Answer (score 1):

Увы, через стандартный placeholder - не выйдет, но всегда могут придти на помощь кастомные решения.

Вот один из них:

```css
.input-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.input-block input,
.input-block label {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input-block input {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  color: #333;
  cursor: text;
}

.input-block label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.input-block input:hover {
  border-color: rgba(0, 19, 255, .45);
}

.input-block input:focus {
  border-color: rgba(0, 19, 255, .65);
}

.input-block input:focus+label,
.input-block input:not(:empty)+label,
.input-block input:not(:placeholder-shown)+label {
  top: -75%;
  font-size: 80%;
  opacity: .65;
}

.input-block input:not(:empty):invalid,
.input-block input:not(:empty):required,
.input-block input:not(:empty):invalid {
  border-color: rgba(231, 76, 60, .5);
  box-shadow: none;
}

.input-block input:invalid,
.input-block input:required,
.input-block input:invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.input-block label {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.input-block label span {
  color: red;
}

.input-block input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  color: #ccc;
  cursor: text;
}

.input-block input:hover {
  border-color: rgba(0, 19, 255, .45);
}

.input-block input:focus {
  border-color: rgba(0, 19, 255, .65);
  color: #333;
}

.input-block input:invalid,
.input-block input:required,
.input-block input:invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.input-block label {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.input-block input,
.input-block label {
  transition: all linear .2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-block">
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="">
  <label>Ваш номер телефона <span>*</span></label>
</div>
```

P.s. по цветам и анимации не пойдёт, наверное, писал давно, но чисто как пример пойдёт.

---

Исчезновение placeholder'а

```css
.input-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.input-block input,
.input-block label {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input-block input {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  color: #333;
  cursor: text;
}

.input-block label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.input-block input:hover {
  border-color: rgba(0, 19, 255, .45);
}

.input-block input:focus {
  border-color: rgba(0, 19, 255, .65);
}

.input-block input:not(:empty)+label,
.input-block input:not(:placeholder-shown)+label {
  opacity: 0;
}

.input-block input:not(:empty):invalid,
.input-block input:not(:empty):required,
.input-block input:not(:empty):invalid {
  border-color: rgba(231, 76, 60, .5);
  box-shadow: none;
}

.input-block input:invalid,
.input-block input:required,
.input-block input:invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.input-block label {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.input-block label span {
  color: red;
}

.input-block input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  color: #444;
  cursor: text;
}

.input-block input:hover {
  border-color: rgba(0, 19, 255, .45);
}

.input-block input:focus {
  border-color: rgba(0, 19, 255, .65);
  color: #333;
}

.input-block input:invalid,
.input-block input:required,
.input-block input:invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.input-block label {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.input-block input,
.input-block label {
  transition: all linear .2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-block">
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="">
  <label>Ваш номер телефона <span>*</span></label>
</div>

<div class="input-block">
  <input type="text" value="124" placeholder="">
  <label>Ваш номер телефона <span>*</span></label>
</div>
```

+ Исчезновение placeholder'а при фокусе

```css
.input-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.input-block input,
.input-block label {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input-block input {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  color: #333;
  cursor: text;
}

.input-block label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.input-block input:hover {
  border-color: rgba(0, 19, 255, .45);
}

.input-block input:focus {
  border-color: rgba(0, 19, 255, .65);
}

.input-block input:focus+label {
  opacity: .5;
}

.input-block input:not(:empty)+label,
.input-block input:not(:placeholder-shown)+label {
  opacity: 0;
}

.input-block input:not(:empty):invalid,
.input-block input:not(:empty):required,
.input-block input:not(:empty):invalid {
  border-color: rgba(231, 76, 60, .5);
  box-shadow: none;
}

.input-block input:invalid,
.input-block input:required,
.input-block input:invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.input-block label {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.input-block label span {
  color: red;
}

.input-block input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  color: #444;
  cursor: text;
}

.input-block input:hover {
  border-color: rgba(0, 19, 255, .45);
}

.input-block input:focus {
  border-color: rgba(0, 19, 255, .65);
  color: #333;
}

.input-block input:invalid,
.input-block input:required,
.input-block input:invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.input-block label {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.input-block input,
.input-block label {
  transition: all linear .2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-block">
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="">
  <label>Ваш номер телефона <span>*</span></label>
</div>

<div class="input-block">
  <input type="text" value="124" placeholder="">
  <label>Ваш номер телефона <span>*</span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: особенность placeholder в том что при вводе текста должно пропадать название

Comment: @Leks, дополнил ответ

Comment: мне надо как в коде OPTIMUS PRIME

Comment: @Leks, дополнил, в этот раз при фокусе placeholder частично исчезает, после ввода текста - полностью

Comment: мне надо открываешь и видишь placeholder и красную звезду водишь текст а placeholderсразу исчезает

Comment: для наглядности посмотрите код выше вашего

Comment: @Leks, они работают одинаково..

Comment: как скажите не буду спорить

Comment: @Leks, в следующий раз, чтобы не было подобного, задавайте вопрос как можно точнее, а лучше с примером. Вопрос об одном, а результат о другом.

Comment: хорошо, извиняюсь если что-то не так

Comment: @Leks, извинения тут лишние, ничего ж не случилось.

Comment: хорошо, удачи (какой-то текст)